# Foldable and Trees

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monoids

I have the following definition of a Tree

```
 data Tree a = Leaf a
           | Node [Tree a] 
     deriving (Show)
```

And the following instance of foldable:

```
 instance Foldable (Tree) where
 foldMap f (Leaf t) = (f t)
 foldMap f (Node t) = (foldMap `mappend` (foldMap f) t)
```

This code throws me and error

```
 Couldn't match type `a' with `Tree a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Tree a -> m
      at trees.hs:8:5
 Expected type: [a]
   Actual type: [Tree a]
```

How do I make t in the instance declaration of type Tree a instead of a?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'll assume that you did indent the code inside the instance declaration, otherwise the compiler would have complained about that.)

The problem is in the line:

```
 foldMap f (Node t) = (foldMap `mappend` (foldMap f) t)
```

what is (foldMap `mappend`  ...) supposed to do? You are treating foldMap itself as a monadic value. I think what you want to do is just `foldMap (foldMap f) t`.

By the way, GHC can derive the Foldable instance for you automatically (as well as Functor and Traversable). Just write

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable #-}
data Tree a = Leaf a
            | Node [Tree a]
  deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable)
```